# js проверка timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Сервлет выводит дату типа Timestamp,не могу понять как сделать проверку при редактировании даты на валидность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ:

```
var valid = (new Date(timestamp)).getTime() > 0;

var valid = (new Date('2012-08-09')).getTime() > 0; /// true
var valid = (new Date('abc')).getTime() > 0; /// false
```

**UPD**
Столкнулся с ситуацией, когда JS не работал MySQL TimeStamp.
Нашел такое решение:

```
Date.mysqlTimeStamp = function(mysql_string){
    var t, result = null;
    if( typeof mysql_string === 'string' )
    {
        t = mysql_string.split(/[- :]/);
        result = new Date(t[0], t[1] - 1, t[2], t[3] || 0, t[4] || 0, t[5] || 0);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Использовать так:

```
timestamp = Date.mysqlTimeStamp(timestamp);
```

**UPD2**
Судя по [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), действительно, *Javascript* не работает с *MySQL TimeStamp*.
Функция `Date.mysqlTimeStamp` дробит строку на составляющие, что бы потом воспользоваться 4-м подходом из документации:

```
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]);
```

> Последовательность в `MySQL TimeStamp` стандартизирована, поэтому можно смело использовать подход из `Date.mysqlTimeStamp` !

Comment: да,но этот способ не сработает если например ввести 2117-09-15 00:00:41.0

Comment: Это был дополнительный вопрос))). Добавил под UPD.

Comment: возможно я изначально неправильно задал вопрос,так как возникли трудности при проверке данных типа 2117-09-15 00:00:41.0 ,не понял как работает Date.mysqlTimeStamp

Comment: Ответил под UPD2.

Answer (score 1):

При работе с датами на javascript вам может помочь замечательный плагин [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).
Вот пример с сайта разработчика, как проверить дату на валидность:

```
var m = moment("2011-10-10T10:20:90");
m.isValid(); // false, дата не корректна
m.invalidAt(); // 5, что означает, что неверно указаны секунды
```

Формат даты также можно настроить под ваши нужды.

Comment: спасибо,проблема уже решилась через максимальное и минимальное значение Timestamp mysql